# How to plot a graph with the motion in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a code in Python to plot a graph. Upon giving the input the graph shall be start playing. Exactly as we see the ECG wave form playing in the ECG monitor. Upon providing the certain input the graph shall start playing as per the input value provided. Please help me regarding this...

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: [matplotlib animation examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/animation/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [rtgraph](http://rtgraph.sourceforge.net/) package. It can do real-time charts. It uses gtk/pygtk on Linux.